# How do I add a recipe to a chef run list?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef node that I'm attempting to add a recipe to. Currently, this node has one recipe in the run list:

```
$ knife node show mynode
Node Name:   mynode
Environment: _default
FQDN:        mynode.domain
IP:          10.8.16.214
Run List:    recipe[mycb::myrecipe1]
Roles:
Recipes:     mycb::myrecipe1, ms_dotnet::ms_dotnet4, ms_dotnet::default, windows::default
Platform:    windows 6.3.9600
Tags:
```

I'm attempting to add a new recipe (mycb::recipe2) to the run list for this node:

```
$ knife node run_list add mynode 'recipe[mycb::myrecipe2]'
mynode:
  run_list:
    recipe[mycb::myrecipe1]
    recipe[recipes]
```

This new recipe `recipe[recipes]` is quite strange. I do not have a cookbook called recipes:

```
$ knife recipe-list
chef-sugar
chef_handler
chef_handler::json_file
mycb
mycb::myrecipe1
mycb::myrecipe2
ms_dotnet
ms_dotnet::ms_dotnet2
ms_dotnet::ms_dotnet3
ms_dotnet::ms_dotnet4
ms_dotnet::regiis
openssl
openssl::upgrade
sql_server
sql_server::client
sql_server::server
windows
windows::reboot_handler
```

I also don't have a cookbook called recipes:

```
$ knife cookbook list
chef-sugar     3.1.0
chef_handler   1.1.9
mycb           0.1.0
ms_dotnet      2.3.0
openssl        4.0.0
sql_server     2.2.3
windows        1.37.0
```

Where is this coming from, and how do I cause the correct recipe to be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are on PowerShell? See https://docs.chef.io/knife_node.html#id19 about escaping the `knife node run_list add` call

Comment: Indeed this was the problem. An open question is "why didn't knife fail". Also, knife.bat should be replaced with knife.ps1 :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** For other users that are not using PowerShell.

I was able to reproduce the same `recipe[recipes]` issue when `knife --version` returns `Chef: 13.6.4`

- Broken `knife` syntax command missing `'` around `recipe[my_cookbook]`

  ```
  knife node run_list add mynode recipe[my_cookbook]
  ```
- Correct `knife` syntax command with `'` around `recipe[my_cookbook]`

  ```
  knife node run_list add mynode 'recipe[my_cookbook]'
  ```